# Rewriting ASP URL and getting Redirect Loop

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a script in place that replaces `example.com/folder/index.php/pagename` with `example.com/pagename`.

But `example.com/pagename` technically doesn't exist - so if someone navigates to it they get a 404.

I tried to add a redirect in my web.config file that looks like:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="my redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="pagename" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/folder/index.php/pagename/" redirectType="permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it's resulting in a redirect loop.  I noticed that if I change the final URL to something different like `example.com/pagenamealternate` that it works just fine.

Can anyone tell me if there's a handy condition or alternative way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a redirect loop because your pattern `pagename` also matches the target URL, which has `pagename` in it.

Change your match url to `^pagename$`, now the rewrite rule only kicks in for requests with the exact url: `example.com/pagename`, you may want to allow additional text after the pagename, then use: `^pagename` as the match pattern.
The `^` in a regular expression means the beginning of a string, this works because the rewrite engine looks at everything after the hostname part.

Also consider a rewrite action rather than a redirect.

Comment: Changing `pagename` to `^pagename$^` did the trick!  Thanks so much!